# how to retrieve pid of a nginx -s reload command in alpine?

Tags: docker, shell, nginx

Im restarting my nginx in a docker container in a sh script and i would like to make sure i retrieve the right pid when doing so.

So nginx is already running and im doing `nginx -s reload` to restart the service.

If I do `nginx -s reload & nginx_pid=$!`, will nginx_pid indeed correspond to nginx pid ?

Thank you

Best

Answer (score 0):

A Docker container only normally runs a single process, and inside the container its process ID is 1.  In an `nginx` container I'd expect the Nginx pid to *always* be 1.  The server won't be process 1 only if there's a separate init process (`tini` is a common one) or if your process is launched by a shell script without using `exec`; the Docker Hub `nginx` image does neither of these things.

In the fragment you show, `nginx -s reload` sends a command to the main Nginx server and exits (and it doesn't need to be run in the background).  `$!` is the pid of that reload command and not the Nginx server.

In typical use you never need to know process IDs inside containers, manually send signals to processes, or otherwise be "inside" a container.  If your application code calls **fork**(2) or **getppid**(2) it can know another process's pid but even these are somewhat unusual.  If you need to restart a container process it's usually simplest to delete and recreate the entire container.

Comment: no the problem is the container restarts because the script is an entrypoint or command script, so one solution in another post was to put wait pid for the nginx process launched in the script